# Microsoft Graph API Bookings - Public URL for booking service

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph Beta REST API for Customer Bookings I would like to retrieve the public link for a specific booking service page, which is available through the MS Bookings app here:

[Booking service sharable URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0NDP.png)

It looks like: [https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/[bookingBusinessEmail]/bookings/s/LdQCYS7WqEa7upCnyiybFg2](https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/%5BbookingBusinessEmail%5D/bookings/s/LdQCYS7WqEa7upCnyiybFg2)

However, it doesn't seem to be in the response body for bookingService or any other resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingservice?view=graph-rest-beta

Is there a way via MS Graphs to get this link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the documentation shared and the Bookings resources, it looks like there isn't yet a way to retrieve the public link using MS Graph.